# C# fill a listbox during the form load event from a Microsoft Access database

Tags: c#, database, listbox

Please, I need some assistance. I have a C# form that has a listbox that I would like to fill during the form load event. When I click on an item, I would like for it to display relevant information in a few textboxes on the form, but the code below does not load the listbox. It does not err, but does not load any values either. I found a post similar to my request on this site, but it did not help.

Here is my code in the load section of a form:

```
        string str = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\\data.mdb;JetOLEDB:DatabasePassword=SomethingGoesHere";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Last_Name FROM Membership_Log", con);
        con.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt;
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        View_Membership_Log_Listview.DataSource = dt;
        View_Membership_Log_Listview.DisplayMember = "Last_Name";
        var value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Last_Name"].ToString();
        var value2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["First_Name"].ToString();
        last_NameTextBox.Text = value;
        first_NameTextBox.Text = value2;
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Look in the Output window for a "First chance exception" notification.  If you see one then move this code into the constructor, where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
View_Membership_Log_Listview.DataSource = dt;
        View_Membership_Log_Listview.DisplayMember = "Last_Name";
        var value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Last_Name"].ToString();
```

To:

```
    Dictionary<string,string> d_Names = new Dictionary<string,string>();

foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
d_Names.Add(row["Last_Name"].ToString(),row["Last_Name"].ToString()); //Last name is the    key, First name could be used as the value or visa versa if needed.
}

View_Membership_Log_Listview.DataSource = d_Names;
        View_Membership_Log_Listview.DisplayMember = "Key";
        View_Membership_Log_Listview.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Hope this helps, I dont have VS open infront of me so please forgive any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, but this code causes an error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' in the body of the foreach loop

Comment: Sorry about that - See the edit. (I changed var to DataRow in the for loop)